# Typescript overloading, and chaining

Tags: typescript

I have this code

```
 thing.doSomething = function(arg?: number[]) {
   return arguments ? 
      ((something = arg), thing) : something.length;
}
```

it's designed to be used as a setter with chaining or getter. Examples:

```
thing.doSomething([1,2,3]).otherMethod()
// or
thing.doSomething() // => 3
```

How do I type this function in order for typesript to not complain when chaining. Whatever I attempted, typescript always treats the return types as OR, not XOR so it can't figure out that when there's input param, the type is fixed.

Comment: I *think* you need [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for this.

Comment: the signatures are not compatible...

Comment: Which signatures? Can you show us what you tried with overloads?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w8KQVW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: `arguments` is always an array, and arrays are always truthy, even if they are empty. So this code does not do what you think it does. It would make more sense to test `arg !== undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

this recipe seems to be doing what I want

```
interface A {
    alabala: number
}

interface X {
    (): void;
    z(x: number): number;
    z(): A;
}

function fun() { }

fun.z = function(_?: number) {
    if (arguments) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return { alabala: 0 }
    }
}

let ff = fun as X;

fun()
let a: A = ff.z()
let b: number = ff.z(1)

console.log(a.alabala)
```